# Unable to delete key from a json in karate framework - remove() and delete did not work

Tags: karate

I want to delete a key from JSON. I found two examples shared by @Peter Thomas. I tried both and unfortunately, none worked.

**Example 1**

```
* def json = { a: 1, b: 2 }
* def key = 'b'
* if (true) karate.remove('json', key)
* match json == { a: 1 }
```

**Error**
javascript evaluation failed: if (true) karate.remove('json', key), unexpected path: b

**Example 2**

```
* def json = { a: 1, b: 2 }
* def key = 'b'
* if (true) delete json[key]
* match json == { a: 1 }
```

**Error**
actual: {a=1, b=2}, expected: {a=1}, reason: actual value has 1 more key(s) than expected: {b=2}

Answer (score 0):

You probably are on an old version. Upgrade. Or maybe it is a bug, so follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue